# TCPDF custom header and footer WriteHTML

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I found out the how-to of custom header footer in tcpdf. But this example http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_003.phps makes use of $this->Cell() . I want to display a table and trying to make use of $this->WriteHTML but that is giving me errors??? Some clue?

```
Errors-> Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: rows

Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php

Line Number: 21355
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually means that html you're trying to display malformed html (table?). Update your question with actual code.